# Services directory not found in AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm using Angular 1.4.6 and I cannot see services directory in app structure. If I added myself it, I cannot see in project source this time.

After add services directory in app structure, build / serve by Grunt but the result did not change.

Whats the problem? How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: angular doesn't have a set structure for folders.  This isn't an issue with angular, but an issue with either your editor of choice or your grunt task which is creating this directory.  Angular won't care if you have a services folder or don't have a services folder, except of course if you ask it to load a script from that folder.

Comment: you will need to import each and every single file inside the index.html